# json_encode is truncating the object data read from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am developing a web application in PHP 5.6.8 with MySql as database engine.

In my method to authenticate the User for appropriate credentials i am making a call to the database and retrieved the user object. The function code is :

```
function getBoosterDetails($patientId){
       $dbConnection = new Database();

       $sql = "SELECT * from users where id = :patientId";
       try {
           $db = $dbConnection->getConnection();
           $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
           $stmt->bindParam("patientId", $patientId);
           $stmt->execute();
           $userDetails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
           $db = null;
           $_SESSION['userDetails'] = $userDetails;

           echo '{"user": ' . json_encode($userDetails) . '}';


       } catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
       } catch(Exception $e1) {
           echo '{"error11":{"text11":'. $e1->getMessage() .'}}'; 
       } }
```

For any valid input I have been getting the error that object is not valid. I tried Inspecting the userDetails object in Advanced Rest Client Chrome Plugin. What I observe is that while the var dump of the object has teh whole object data the echo of json_encode has truncation as displayed in the below image.

![enter image description here][1]

I have setup the Apache & MySql Servers with XAMPP (and also tried with MAMP earlier and met with the same result.)

```
// this is the var_dump
    stdClass object
(
    [username]  => pavan
    [rolename]  => Patient
    [userid]  => 5
)

//this is the json_encode echo output
{"user": [{"username":"pavan", "rolename":"Patient", "userid":
```

The content is getting truncated when it is json encoded
Could you please help me out resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap json-in-json. That's just wrong.

Build one SINGLE data structure in your host language (e.g. php), then encode the ENTIRE structure:

```
$data = array(
   'user' => $userDetails
);
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Your code is producing syntactically ILLEGAL json...

```
   echo '{"user":' . json_encode($userDetails) . '}}';**
         ^--open #1                               ^--close #1
                                                   ^--close #2
```

What is this #2 brace closing? If you done the single-structure encode, this would have been impossible.

Comment: Tried what you suggested but still similar error: {"user":[{"username":"pavan","rolename":"Others","userid":"00000000

Comment: mysql and json_encode won't truncate something out of the blue. verify that what you're expecting is really there, e.g. `var_dump($userDetails)`.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the response: i have made the var_dump and this is what it displays:  // this is the var_dump
    stdClass object
(
    [username]  => pavan
    [rolename]  => Patient
    [userid]  => 000000005
)

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code instead of existing one?

We just changed PDO::FETCH_OBJ to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, it returns array format.

Updated code:

function getBoosterDetails($patientId){
       $dbConnection = new Database();

```
   $sql = "SELECT * from users where id = :patientId";
   try {
       $db = $dbConnection->getConnection();
       $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam("patientId", $patientId);
       $stmt->execute();
       $userDetails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $db = null;
       $_SESSION['userDetails'] = $userDetails;

       echo '{"user": ' . json_encode($userDetails) . '}';


   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
   } catch(Exception $e1) {
       echo '{"error11":{"text11":'. $e1->getMessage() .'}}'; 
   } }
```